# Where can I find a reference for the definition of the biquadratic bicyclic number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Where can I find a reference for the definition of the biquadratic bicyclic number field? Any link also will be appreciated.

I am not sure why I got a -1 here, but I first had a look online, I was looking for a formal definition containing ' bicyclic'.The below answer is helpful. I also found [this](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272482/1-s2.0-S0022314X00X00571/1-s2.0-S0022314X99923776/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKT%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIEj1ht%2BCbCaBYVxbVdv1zRoChV7reMXhJc70Dy4trjMZAiEAlAB8b2vxgIqvrsbg3kOfXDBJz0dRQbRA8mx2qeRlkG0qvAUInf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDJSiDqMXLzsbOLEbpyqQBTqS7wnITTLfAt%2FeKosClla7c196OikC87s663lpNojYR7vQuPjT3O5gRX58H9OfP97RGbUk4H5Zepflk%2BdDBh1NDL9%2F7xC2XOVSTlISAnL9NWXYZq4OG687eCKHaSjcDTrXBWdfKgcSXIWxBfqD7O%2Btu9BE7XSQcUYcT78m0juFx7e3J2cSkPcFs0K8sXSKuYQXbvmZD%2BFAajyOS7WnaKULaeDGoaCZoQhXTaatdXREzMjIz6uvFDJjkNW4%2FZwy5jDgid%2BJYjjf3VlxwKvXY49B0dY7r0yMEBPVAd%2FyYIvhvdRssQs6lZkle3ZRLEEd%2FBv6ta9o3JAXwFaDWjGzjmxUXO7%2FmQaiYMktuwqycEGAJWuODzHnu%2BxSdWNnlb5VS%2BteiG210GPeM6IyyqPDbd4eFGdtwktxzp2gwZ4WOdOcIww1SVx7kWOK2JTF20%2B2PO%2F3olOf23kc8jA0iA1FbiWfAECiuduYpzZ6r17BS6AyrjDeJAdy%2FjorV4x9z7mWU80SkNUlsS1YniWfv2z1zO94VT1Ol6x4hgJkBLXQBnoBQf7YhL1lqL02fzQcKUwF6o2CXCwxMQYitIOcMVYeb0R4VKHNDt%2BLZekgdLAJ5s06G6A00nCNue4AgBGF%2BT2jEwvy%2FE6dkhZhNTpl8LLfmcFYVUggxr3JXXr6YutDpILCrn%2FUJf0eUhQ587WFHnmEOSdegvwWXDjJN1WmKTFS1vS%2B0iZiCE1MT52ELUMFgkFw6gTCkEYL4putytU2gVojwQIj0p7nFDYxKiCU3BCPbboIQAM4U7FPcPKqaDD5iMdccyrO4OvSTvFgi2607TGDHEpV8v%2FRudj3bAJa3zpttb24zJ5xdE43f3kT0NFCv7JDMIqPiKIGOrEBve0tKlu580UUeV8MEzm8qH81ix5EgqAfgBTACfhF3fPm7zhklMeB92CVPgAtCbUTr2yhsUbZm5vskmCUzTKhJ8ykQ3iGs7USv4mwhm6AjuFxMirUUUxU8iMFEUk7OlevNJzYsmfG%2F2reBsJKHIXUoMhYso8mZnPz0iSx%2FtZmGmsboU25Mf0hZ80OdcZXAP65YW08z8ZOtA8lV9kxfMzmKPeW1jq2rdUUqFvm2O7aESYm&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230421T050208Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSAHYMEFR%2F20230421%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0e937336764eb2a71dcb267746481cfa859c23db459dbb30fe1c5db79d4fa8b5&hash=edb48bf18243e7af2a8c8673234dc8f7584641aa297e2fcc4b9fb180e358b2e0&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022314X99923776&tid=spdf-2b70908c-cfab-467a-8598-2ea9b631062b&sid=40338dec86402148a57ba221569a578de2cagxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=05015000035152510659&rr=7bb312b7ccda30a6&cc=ca). Since all the biquadratic number fields are bicyclic, I couldn't get the reason why we have 'bicyclic' there. but in the above link and as mentioned in the below answer, I realized this definition is for a general Galios quartic extension.

Comment: If your search for this term, you obtain many links, e.g. [this one](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj6pvyr0rr-AhWeg_0HHeHDDKMQFnoECCMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fnagoya-mathematical-journal%2Fvolume-102%2Fissue-none%2FImaginary-bicyclic-biquadratic-fields-with-the-real-quadratic-subfield-of%2Fnmj%2F1118780410.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0-6khpS-bT7YGac1dQbfVr). You can also find it separately. First see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquadratic_field) for biquadratic number field.

Comment: Don't be stingy with the information in your title. It's OK to repeat the question from the body in the title, if it is concise.  Hiding it in the body of the question will limit attention to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwigsK7yh7v-AhUESuUKHfqwCqIQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs10998-017-0233-9&usg=AOvVaw1G1H2sknkPEXwMmR0XoyDr) is one of many links with an explicit definition:

**Definition:** Let $m, n ∈ \Bbb Z \setminus \{0, 1\}$ be distinct square-free rational integers. Then number fields of the form $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m},\sqrt{n})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})$
are called bicyclic biquadratic fields.

**Remark:** These are the
quartic number fields whose Galois group is the Kleinian group $C_2\times C_2$. Therefore the name *bicyclic*.